# Ckeditor - Not displaying text on edit node option

Tags: users, wysiwyg

I've been using [Ckeditor](http://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) for a while to add text to created nodes.

But when editing the same nodes as an authenticated user, Ckeditor doesn't show the text in the body.

It still works for the administration role.

Comment: Do you mean that no text appears at all, or that the authenticated user cannot see the CKEditor interface?

Comment: The Authenticated user can see the Ckeditor interface, but not the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the Ckeditor, its usually due to the security update.

Do a update or uninstalling and reinstalling the Ckeditor and

do [download](http://ckeditor.com/download) the newest Ckeditor and

place in the `sites\all\modules\ckeditor\ckeditor`.

Just enable the module and clear the cache and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 3):

You have to give the `Authenticated user` role the rights to use the input format CKEditor used to save the page. Look on the access rights page, URL depending on  Drupal version.

Comment: All rights given to the Authenticated user to access, edit Ckeditor for the Drupal 7 version.

Comment: And the input format too, like in `Use Full HTML input format` ?

Comment: Yes! its a `Full HTML` input format!

Comment: I've forgotten this few times. Editing some text as admin and setting it to full-html, Bang, author cant access it bc authenticated user has only filtered html.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the permission 'VIEW THE ADMINISTRATION THEME' for that role in admin/people/permissions

Answer (score 0):

I had a blank page issue after upgrading to the newest ckeditor 4.5. All I did to correct it is to go the top of the browser of the editing page and refresh. Then everything started populating correctly. I hope this works for you as well. Give a feedback if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Authenticated user and admin have the same text format permissions? 
If the admin use the "full html" and the authenticated user use "filtered html", then the ckeditor will strip the html tags for "filtered html", check the ckeditor content filtering options.

You can turn off the filtering, but not an good ideea for security ...

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

Document more about `config.allowedContent` and how to allow specific tags for user input.